# Lua help me optimize my pattern-matching function

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

Is there a way to get rid of the last two gsub and make this function use single replacement table for all catch patterns?

```
function sanitize(txt)
    local replacements = {
        ['&' ] = '&amp;', 
        ['<' ] = '&lt;', 
        ['>' ] = '&gt;', 
        ['\n'] = '<br/>'
    }
    return txt
        :gsub('[&<>\n]', replacements)
        :gsub(' +', ' ')
        :gsub('%^%d', '')
end
```

Comment: In Lua patterns, you cannot use alternation. So, you cannot merge the 3 patterns into one.

Comment: But he can place the last two as string index keys into the replacement table and let the pattern  ```'.'``` in gsub() searching for replacements.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correct then do something like...

```
function sanitize(txt)
    local replacements = {
        ['&'] = '&amp;', 
        ['<'] = '&lt;', 
        ['>'] = '&gt;', 
        ['\n'] = '<br/>',
        ['+'] = '',
        ['^'] = '',
        ['1'] = '',
        ['2'] = '',
        ['3'] = '',
        ['4'] = '',
        ['5'] = '',
        ['6'] = '',
        ['7'] = '',
        ['8'] = '',
        ['9'] = '',
        ['0'] = ''
    }
    return txt:gsub('.', replacements)
end
```

Comment: In the initial code the last two gsub are used for formatting something like "^1te^2st1^       2string3^" into "test1^ 2string3" (catching ^%d and multiple spaces) but your solution does "test       string"

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to make this function use single replacement table for all catch patterns?

Yes.
But you would not want to use it :-)

```
function sanitize(txt)
   local replacements = {
      -- only up to 3 spaces; add more entries to this table for longer chains of spaces
      ['&' ] = '&amp;', ['& ' ] = '&amp; ', ['&  ' ] = '&amp; ', ['&   ' ] = '&amp; ',
      ['<' ] = '&lt;',  ['< ' ] = '&lt; ',  ['<  ' ] = '&lt; ',  ['<   ' ] = '&lt; ',
      ['>' ] = '&gt;',  ['> ' ] = '&gt; ',  ['>  ' ] = '&gt; ',  ['>   ' ] = '&gt; ',
      ['\n'] = '<br/>', ['\n '] = '<br/> ', ['\n  '] = '<br/> ', ['\n   '] = '<br/> ',
      ['  ' ] = ' ', ['   ' ] = ' ',

      ['0  '] = '0 ', ['0   '] = '0 ',
      ['1  '] = '1 ', ['1   '] = '1 ',
      ['2  '] = '2 ', ['2   '] = '2 ',
      ['3  '] = '3 ', ['3   '] = '3 ',
      ['4  '] = '4 ', ['4   '] = '4 ',
      ['5  '] = '5 ', ['5   '] = '5 ',
      ['6  '] = '6 ', ['6   '] = '6 ',
      ['7  '] = '7 ', ['7   '] = '7 ',
      ['8  '] = '8 ', ['8   '] = '8 ',
      ['9  '] = '9 ', ['9   '] = '9 ',

      ['^&' ] = '^&amp;', ['^& ' ] = '^&amp; ', ['^&  ' ] = '^&amp; ', ['^&   ' ] = '^&amp; ',
      ['^<' ] = '^&lt;',  ['^< ' ] = '^&lt; ',  ['^<  ' ] = '^&lt; ',  ['^<   ' ] = '^&lt; ',
      ['^>' ] = '^&gt;',  ['^> ' ] = '^&gt; ',  ['^>  ' ] = '^&gt; ',  ['^>   ' ] = '^&gt; ',
      ['^\n'] = '^<br/>', ['^\n '] = '^<br/> ', ['^\n  '] = '^<br/> ', ['^\n   '] = '^<br/> ',
      ['^ '] = ' ', ['^  '] = ' ', ['^   '] = ' ',

      ['^0'] = '', ['^0 '] = ' ', ['^0  '] = ' ', ['^0   '] = ' ',
      ['^1'] = '', ['^1 '] = ' ', ['^1  '] = ' ', ['^1   '] = ' ',
      ['^2'] = '', ['^2 '] = ' ', ['^2  '] = ' ', ['^2   '] = ' ',
      ['^3'] = '', ['^3 '] = ' ', ['^3  '] = ' ', ['^3   '] = ' ',
      ['^4'] = '', ['^4 '] = ' ', ['^4  '] = ' ', ['^4   '] = ' ',
      ['^5'] = '', ['^5 '] = ' ', ['^5  '] = ' ', ['^5   '] = ' ',
      ['^6'] = '', ['^6 '] = ' ', ['^6  '] = ' ', ['^6   '] = ' ',
      ['^7'] = '', ['^7 '] = ' ', ['^7  '] = ' ', ['^7   '] = ' ',
      ['^8'] = '', ['^8 '] = ' ', ['^8  '] = ' ', ['^8   '] = ' ',
      ['^9'] = '', ['^9 '] = ' ', ['^9  '] = ' ', ['^9   '] = ' ',
   }
   return txt:gsub('%^?[&<>\n%d ] *', replacements)
end
```